# Kurento 6.0 setup on AWS instance having ubuntu OS

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, kurento, rfc5766turnserver

I have some doubts and I need some clarification on that, this is regarding the Kurento 6.0 server setup on AWS instance having ubuntu 14.04.
1: I have setup the Kurento successfully.
2: I also installed the turnserver.
3: I configured the turnserver as guided here.
4: I follow that link till here...
...know how many Media Pipelines do I need for my Application?
After doing all setting I run this commands...
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world
git checkout 6.2.1
mvn compile exec:java

After this I get my kurento is successfully running as putting log into end of the question.
I am doing all this by connecting my instance remotely using WinScp.
After this I try to access it on my windows machine in browser (Chrome/Mozilla), 
I try the urls: http://:8080 and https://:8443
But I found the result as server not found.
On the same instance I have PHP Apache server I am able to get that on http://:80
Can any once tell me that what mistake I am doing here? Or any once can tell me is this possible to access kurento server into local machines browser, if yes than how?
Thanks in advance.

---

### Heading

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add log Here it is.------------------------------------.
  - Connecting to kms in ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
13:05:44.560 [HelloWorldApp.main()] DEBUG - o.kurento.jsonrpc.client.JsonRpcClient   -  Enabling heartbeat with an interval of 240000 ms
13:05:44.562 [     pool-3-thread-1] DEBUG - o.k.j.client.JsonRpcClientWebSocket      - [KurentoClient]  Connecting webSocket client to server ws://127.0.0.1:8888/kurento
13:05:45.388 [HelloWorldApp.main()] INFO  - o.k.tutorial.helloworld.HelloWorldApp    - Started HelloWorldApp in 3.061 seconds (JVM running for 9.699)

Comment: This question has been asked and answered in the project's public mailing list. Thread [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/tbnfydZXovY%5B1-25%5D)

Comment: Thanks Ivan and kurento Group I got the answer of this question from Ivan on mail group. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to make sure that you've edited the AWS instance's security group to allow inbound traffic on the ports you're using.

Also, I've personally had minor difficulty pointing a browser at my AWS server using its public DNS, so try a url like this:

```
http://<your AWS instance's public IP>:<port>
```

Comment: This is exactly what was missing in the setup, along with the path where the application is deployed.

Comment: Thanks -@ohnoapirate